# Как добавить изображение на видео Python?

Tags: python, изображения, видео

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой, нужно на большое количество видео наложить изображение(видео лежат в одной папке, доступны их название и прочая информация о файле) изображение накладывать нужно одно и то же. Не подскажите инструмент для этого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать [moviepy](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/).
Вот [пример кода](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/127) для добавления изображения на видео:

```python
import moviepy.editor as mp

video = mp.VideoFileClip("video.mp4")

logo = (mp.ImageClip("logo.png")
          .set_duration(video.duration)
          .resize(height=50) # если необходимо поменять размер...
          .margin(right=8, top=8, opacity=0) # (опционально) logo-border padding
          .set_pos(("right","top")))

final = mp.CompositeVideoClip([video, logo])
final.write_videofile("test.mp4")
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!